# Find rank of a sub-matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, rank

I have a matrix `g` of shape `[4, 4, 2, 2]` where I need to find the rank of `g[0, 0]`, `g[1, 1]`, `g[2, 2]` and `g[3, 3]` which are all `2x2` matrices. I used the `tf.rank` operator but it treats `g` as a single array and computes the rank and returns a single value for the whole matrix. What I need is a `2x2` matrix of ranks of the corresponding `g[i, j]`'s.
Following is a MWE:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
 [[[ 0., 0.], [ 0., 0.]], [[-1., -1.], [-1., -1.]], [[-2., -2.], [-2., -2.]], [[-3., -3.], [-3., -3.]]], 
 [[[ 1., 1.], [ 1., 1.]], [[ 0., 0.], [ 0., 0.]], [[-1., -1.], [-1., -1.]], [[-2., -2.], [-2., -2.]]],
 [[[ 2., 2.], [ 2., 2.]], [[ 1., 1.], [ 1., 1.]], [[ 0., 0.], [ 0., 0.]], [[-1., -1.], [-1., -1.]]],
 [[[ 3., 3.], [ 3., 3.]], [[ 2., 2.], [ 2., 2.]], [[ 1., 1.], [ 1., 1.]], [[ 0., 0.], [ 0., 0.]]]
])
rank = tf.rank(a)  # Returns a number
```

Apart from using a `for` loop is there any way to get this rank matrix? Thanks.

Comment: In TensorFlow terms, the [rank](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/rank) is simply the number of dimensions of a tensor. Are you referring to the [rank in the linear algebra sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra))?

Comment: @jdehesa I was not aware of that. Yes, I do mean the rank in linear algebra sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any function to compute matrix rank in TensorFlow. One possibility is to use [`tf.linalg.svd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/svd) and count the number of nonzero singular values:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

EPS = 1e-6
a = tf.ones((4, 4, 2, 2), tf.float32)
s = tf.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False, compute_uv=False)
r = tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.abs(s) > EPS, axis=-1)
print(r.numpy())
# [[1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1]
#  [1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: if you set `a` to be `[[[[ 0., 0.],   [ 0., 0.]],  [[-1., -1.],   [-1., -1.]],  [[-2., -2.],   [-2., -2.]],  [[-3., -3.],   [-3., -3.]]], [[[ 1.,  1.],   [ 1.,  1.]],  [[ 0.,  0.],   [ 0.,  0.]],  
[[-1., -1.],   [-1., -1.]],  [[-2., -2.],   [-2., -2.]]], [[[ 2.,  2.],   [ 2.,  2.]],  [[ 1.,  1.],   [ 1.,  1.]],  [[ 0.,  0.],   [ 0.,  0.]],  [[-1., -1.],   [-1., -1.]]], 
[[[ 3.,  3.],   [ 3.,  3.]],  [[ 2.,  2.],   [ 2.,  2.]],  [[ 1.,  1.],   [ 1.,  1.]],  [[ 0.,  0.],   [ 0.,  0.]]]]`, you get `r` to have `2`'s on the diagonal whereas it should have been `0`'s.

Comment: @learner Sorry, the comparison with `EPS` was the other way around (you need the number of singular values _larger_ than epsilon).

Comment: can you maybe look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167217/gradient-not-defined-tensorflow) question? It is sort of a follow up question, thanks.